# Problem in creating python package from Pytorch lightning module

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I want to create a python package that utilizes PyTorch lightening. If in the source code of one of the files in the package, I include this `import pytorch_lightning as pl`, then I cannot use the package. Specifically, I get this error whenever I import the package:

```
torch.cuda.DeferredCudaCallError: CUDA call failed lazily at initialization with error: device >= 0 && device < num_gpus INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at "../aten/src/ATen/cuda/CUDAContext.cpp":50, please report a bug to PyTorch.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an error related to GPU hardware. Most likely, one or more of the GPUs on your machine malfunctioned and is no longer available for use. You can check the status using the `nvidia-smi` command.

In your code, add the following line before your `import torch` statement.

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '<your available GPU IDs>'
```